# append text to a textarea with line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textarea, line-breaks

I want to add some strings to a `textarea` which are file basenames. Everything is fine, but the only problem is that it mixes all the values and there are not any line breaks:

```
var file_name = file.file_name;
var base = new String(file_name).substring(file_name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
if(base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1)       
base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
$('textarea#image_Basename').append(base).split('\n');
```

These are my file basenames:

```
5b0cd65710052633dc5dcac406a382c4
212asaddgcvjh622sdsds22113554dfd
5sd5weea55rr6qasfdjkloijhj665s6a
```

But after storing the data in to the database and retrieving it, the result I get is:

```
5b0cd65710052633dc5dcac406a382c4212asaddgcvjh622sdsds22113554dfd5sd5weea55rr6qasfdjkloijhj665s6a
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the content of `file_name` as it is before manipulating it?

Comment: I'm uploading the file and I use this on uploadsuccess: `'onUploadSuccess' : function(data, file, response) {file = JSON.parse(file);var file_name = file.file_name;`

and the file name is like: `file_name = 5b0cd65710052633dc5dcac406a382c4.jpg`

Comment: I've updated my answer to support two ways of dealing with the problem.

Comment: There seems not to be `/` characters, nor `\n`s in the `file_name`, also there's only one file name...

Comment: @Teemu This function might be called multiple times, in which case there would be multiple filenames being appended, like the three above.

Comment: Ahaa.. Then rink's answer should work, at least for the `textarea`...

Comment: @Teemu, yes his second method worked for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve newlines that are coming from a database or whatever, replace the newline characters with the HTML entity for a line feed: `&#xA;`

```
base = base.replace("\n", '&#xA;');
$('#image_Basename').append(base);
```

If you're trying to append each string with a newline at the end, just concatenate it onto the string:

```
$('#image_Basename').append(base + '&#xA;');
```

Also, you're using split on the `textarea` jQuery element, which doesn't make sense as it is an `object` not a `string`.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work ! I'm storing it in to the database, and after retrieving it, I get the mixed value

Comment: yes, finally after using `$('#image_Basename').append(base + '&#xA;');`, I could get what I wanted :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My Special thanks to @rink.attendant.6, his second method worked for me :) The answer is:

```
$('#image_Basename').append(base + '&#xA;');
```

After adding this, I got all the file basenames in separate lines!